# installing ubuntu 14.04 x32

Tags: 14.04

it's my first time installing Ubuntu on my desktop I've tried more than 5 copies, 3 usbs and programs ,2 cd's, changed the BIOS settings , used the special boot menu but have the same result:

When I chose to *run ubuntu inside windows 8 32* this happens:

```
Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

When it's booting from the boot menu this happens:

```
(mounting /dev/loop0 on//filesystem.squashfs failed: no such device not mount.
/dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //file system.squashfs
```

I tried to install it by VM and every thing was good.

Why I can't install it?

Comment: do you mean along-side or inside as in wubi? because wubi doesn't work anymore.

Comment: right click the iso file and select burn to disk. do not extract the iso do not drag and drop or do anything else. AGAIN, do this ONLY: right-click on the downloaded .iso file and select "burn to disk" from the dropdown menu.

Comment: After you do that, go into your BIOS settings and set your DVD drive as the first device on the list of bootloader devices. Then, with the disk loaded in the drive, reboot. Ubuntu should load.

Comment: yes x86  32 bit    kasiyA
i want to install it along side with my windows 8

Comment: mchid that doesn't work 've tried it

Comment: Use http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ to burn the ISO to an (empty!) USB stick with at least 2GB. Then boot from this USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Ubuntu inside Window's 8?  From your question, I take it you want to install and dual boot? Please read the detailed answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), for the best solution. For starters, dual booting on Windows 8 is only supported ob x64 bit operating systems, as far as I am aware.

Also please be more specific with what you are doing - what ISO are you buring, using what tool? Rufus, Pen Drive Linux etc. As mchid said, [Wubi is no longer supported,](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice) so you need to try a separate method. Please refer to the first link I provided, and if this does not answer your question please add more information in.

If you want some more info, [read up here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: sorry 
ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386 << this copy of ubuntu

Comment: the tools are power iso and Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6

Comment: my windows 8.1 is 32 bit

Comment: Mazen,please provide a step-by-step guide of what you are doing. When you try to boot to the USB, does it work, or does it not respond?

Comment: Michael Nancarrow  all my copies were 32 bit of ubuntu right now i'm downloadin the 64 bit 
ammm yes my usb boots but when i press install ubuntu or try ubunto   while the ubunto screen is loading it gives me this eror
(mounting /dev/loop0 on//filesystem.squashfs failed: no such device not mount.
/dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //file system.squashfs

Comment: sorry i can't speake english very well

Comment: @mazen that's fine, no judgement. Can you please (just to test the burning method, as the error seems dependant of the burning) try using Rufus with the parameter UEFI or MBR and advise?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and for me the think that worked was, earlier i was using rufus with default mode of creating the bootable usb but when i shifted to 'dd' mode of copying, it worked like charm and partition scheme changed to GPT.